# How can I programmatically insert data (rows) to a custom entity table?

Tags: entities, 9

I am using Drupal 9 and I am somewhat of a newbie.

I have created a custom entity into which I wish to log the date and number of image downloads.
I can use the entity's form to create entries but I need to do it programmatically, when the user triggers a download action from the site. The only thing known at that point is the user id and the number of images in the download.
How do I tell my module to create an entity record, being as I am triggering it from a function.
When using the form in debug mode, I can see the variables being passed through but I have no idea as to how to get that data into the database.
My function currently gets the number of images but nothing else.

Do I need to create a hook and if so, how do I trigger that from the download function?

I appreciate any advice anyone can give.

Comment: Partially, @PatrickKenny.
I get a record in the image_downlaods table but as I added a field to the entity through the UI (for the date), the new entity data doesn't get added to that table, so I am unable to get my downloaded date.

I did that because the date column I had in the main table wasn't being brought into the view.
It seems I may have a different issue there, with exposing the column to the view as a date field.
I'll keep digging.

Comment: I have resolved it, using the advice given by @PatrickKenny and also realising that I could use the 'created' BaseFeidDefinition to get me a timestamp in the baseTable.
This can be marked 'solved'